# What is the meaning of "sticks" as a measurement unit?

Tags: measuring-units

I have stumbled upon this sign at the Heraklion airport, Crete, Greece:

[image: Hellenic Duty Free Shops ALLOWANCES TO U.K.* Cigarettes 800 Sticks Cigarillos 400 Sticks Cigars 200 Sticks Smoking Tobacco 1kg Wine (of which no more than 60 litres sparkling) 90 Lit Spirits 10 Lit Fortified Wine (such as port and sherry) 20 Lit Beer 110 Let *ACCORDING TO HM CUSTOMS & EXCISE RULES (www.hmce.gov.uk) *PEOPLE UNDER THE AGE OF 18 ARE NOT ENTITLED TO THE TOBACCO OR ALCOHOL ALLOWANCES.]

I am a little confused about the meaning of "sticks". Is it a metaphor for one stick-shaped unit like a cigar or cigarette, or is it a weight or volume unit?

Comment: The [limits](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/customs/arriving/arrivingeu.htm) are 800 cigarettes etc, so "stick-shaped thing" seems reasonable. I'm not sure how we can second-guess exactly how the Greeks arrived at *stick* though.

Comment: One point to make is that it must be a very old sign. Since Greece and the UK are both members of the EU, there are nowadays no restrictions, and no customs duty on any of these items.

Comment: @WS2 Did you read my link? There are no limits, but there are allowances where you won't be asked awkward questions about your personal consumption of addictive substances [and possible avoidance of UK duty]. Those allowances were set in 2011 (when the figure for cigarettes was dramatically reduced).

Comment: @AndrewLeach No, apologies. I must have missed your comment. But just for the record there is no 'duty'. It is totally abolished in the EU. The only thing you can be charged is an 'excise tax', and that only applies to things which are not for your personal consumption. So the sign is technically incorrect in being titled 'Duty-free Allowances'.

Comment: Incorrect but good marketing

Comment: The sign is not titled "Duty Free Allowances". At the top there's a logo for the brand-name of that mall chain (which happens to include the word "Duty"). the sign would appear to indicate "Allowances" to the UK (perhaps under some broad range of regulations / taxes / systems).

Comment: @JoeBlow There is no longer such as thing as customs duty for countries within the EU. However traders try to maintain the idea that there is, so that travellers stick to the habits of a lifetime in buying vast quantities of alcohol and tobacco as they board the plane home from their holiday. In the UK there is justification for this because of a thing called an 'excise tax'.

Comment: hi WS2. (Just TBC --  if I'm not mistaken, I did not mention "Duty" in any way at all, other than mentioning that the  four letter word "Duty" is part of a company name.) I don't know (at all, in any way) what "Duty" means: i.e.: I have utterly no idea, whatsoever, about the distinctions between "tax" "vat" "tva" "duty" "excise" "sales tax" "special petrol tax" and so on. However **as I understand it** when (for example) a Brit or Suede returns to Brit'land or Suede'land (**from within the EU**), in fact you can only take **enough for "personal use"** and there are various other ....

Comment: ... restrictions such as "you must be personally driving a car" or "certain specific types of trailer over certain heights/etc are disallowed".  (Eg, govt web site, http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/customs/arriving/arrivingeu.htm )  **I have heard that** the "personal use" guideline *(just as with most soft govt guidelines, relating to immigration, visa, and money issues, which are deliberately left open-ended)* comes down to "900 bottles" or whatever in the countries in question.

Comment: Please note that I wrote the following sentence which I created **with extreme precision and care**: *"The sign would appear to indicate 'Allowances' to the UK (perhaps under some broad range of regulations / taxes / systems)."*

Comment: Hey @AdamMatan - i think nobody has pointed out, you would never say this in English!

Comment: I think Andrew found the answer.  "Stick" is a translation for some Greek word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sticks refers to the stick-shaped objects and is used as a hypernym for *cigarette*, *cigarillo* and *cigar* for clarity.

As a unit of measurement it is a bit imprecise, as not all cigars (and even cigarettes) contain the same amount of tobacco. However, it has the advantage of being very easy to implement and to use. Especially in the context of customs and excise duties, this kind of imprecise but easy-to-use measurement is very useful, as you do not need a scale (or worse, lab analysis) to check if someone is carrying too much tobacco or alcohol.

The use of *sticks* like this I have usually seen in this context. It makes a table like on your picture easier to read, but in plain text I have seen the rules explained more clearly:

> A maximum of 800 cigarettes **or** 400 cigarillos **or** 200 cigars **or** 1 kg of tobacco.

The fact that you are (probably) not allowed 800 cigarettes *and* 200 cigars is not clear from the picture, but my guess is that the rule is still the same... when coming form outside Europe.
Inside the EU these restriction are now no more than guidelines, of course, rendering the *and*/*or* distinction academic.

As for the choice of the word *stick*, although the stick-shape of a cigarette is obviously the basis for that, I have heard it used in several countries (at least Greece and India) to refer to individual tobacco-items as opposed to the *pack* measure. In these (and many other) countries, cigarettes are not only sold by the pack, but often individually. In the Netherlands, “two BrandX” will get you 38 cigarettes, but in India I found it necessary to specify whether I wanted 2 *packs* or 2 *sticks*. The hypernym is very handy in places where there is not much semantic distinction between cigars, cigarettes and possibly other tobacco products.

---

As for references of the word *stick* being used for cigarettes, there is of course the meaning of [marijuana cigarette](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stick) or the pejorative [cancer stick](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cancer%20stick).

It seems the simple meaning of *cigarette*, although I have seen it at (some) airports, is not common, except in Indian English, where a quick search reveals many examples of the use:

> This Budget is likely to make tobacco products even more costlier with health ministry proposing hike in tax on cigarettes by Rs 3.5 per stick.
>   [(*from Times of India*)](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Hike-tax-on-cigarettes-by-Rs-3-50/stick-Harsh-Vardhan-says/articleshow/36919936.cms)
>   If the Health Ministry has its way, you will soon be paying Rs.3 more/per stick of your favourite brand of cigarette.
>   [(*from The Hindu*)](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-newdelhi/cigarette-may-cost-rs-3-per-stick-more/article6137759.ece)

Note that in Indian press, [*bidis*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bidi) are mentioned alongside cigarettes, and they are also counted in *sticks*.

[PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20364610) also has an instance of *stick* as cigarette:

> Tobacco contents and length of single stick of different brands of cigarette and bidi were also measured.

I guess in general referencing to a cigarette as a stick simply falls under definition 5 as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick) gives it:

> something prepared (as by cutting, molding, or rolling) in a relatively long and slender often cylindrical form

Comment: The [HMRC website](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/customs/arriving/arrivingeu.htm) indicates that in this case [EU transfer between Greece and the UK], it is actually **and** and not **or**.  At least, that's how I read it, since tobacco and alcohol are listed in exactly the same way and it's unlikely to mean 800 cigarettes or 90 litres of wine.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: of course there strictly are _no_ limits anymore in this case, so the _and_/_or_ distinction is academic. The only question is whether you can convince customs that you only have stuff for personal use.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide a reference to a dictionary or other source?

Comment: It's strange that this site has suddenly become the "travel.stackexchange" site  :)  Isn't the question here "does sticks mean cigarettes?"  **"are now no more than guidelines..."** Here's a gov't web site stating laws http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/customs/arriving/arrivingeu.htm

Comment: @JoeBlow The question is purely linguistic. I travelled to Israel (not the UK), and I don't smoke.

Comment: Adam - thanks for clarifying that!  So it is now clear that we should stick to that topic!

Comment: @oerkelens - regarding your report from Greece and India.  Are you saying you heard it used **in those native languages, ie, an equivalent Greek or Indian word to 'stick'**, or did you mean that (as in the sign shown in the OP), you have seen/heard (which?) it used in an English-as-a-second-language sense (i.e., exactly as in the sign shown in the OP).  Cheers

Comment: @Joe That HMRC link was mentioned by Andrew, and it does indeed mention "there are no limits on the amount of alcohol and tobacco you can bring in from EU countries". But indeed, it _does_ sound like travel advice. I added a bit more on the word _stick_.

Comment: I heard it used _in English_ in Greece and India. That is, I have seen similar signs as the one in the question in Greece and I have _heard and seen_ the word stick being used regularly in Indian English (also by native speakers of Indian English).

Comment: @AdamMatan: I added some references :)

Comment: travel advice corner: "no limits" ...  http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/customs/arriving/arrivingeu.htm  consider sentences like **you must meet the conditions below**, and "unlimited amount of **MOST** goods", and "If you don't meet these conditions, **the goods** and any **vehicle that transported them**, **may be** seized.", and so on.

Comment: Superb references !!

Comment: IMO one should now use, in native English, stick, as a loan-word from non-native-English. (Is there a word for that?)  {Noting of course that Indian-English is not really non-native-English; it's a different thing from a Greek sign-writing company.}

Answer (score 4):

I think they refer to single units of product. (800 cigarettes, 200 cigars)

[Stick](http://www.yourdictionary.com/stick):

> - something shaped like a stick; sticklike piece: a stick of chewing gum

Source: www.yourdictionary.com

Comment: That is *a lot* of cigarettes.

Comment: 1kg of tobacco ~ 1000 cigarettes

Answer (score 1):

"Is it a metaphor for one stick-shaped unit like a cigar or cigarette?"

**Yes.**

Just to be perfectly clear **YOU WOULD NEVER SAY THIS IN ENGLISH.**  It is a non-native-English usage by a non-native-English sign-maker.

It's a curiosity that, as far as I know, there is no superset word for "cigarette or cigar" in English.

{Perhaps someone in the industry could tell us if there is a term usually used **in the industry** for that superset. But as far as I know there is no general word in English for that superset.}

---

The question might arise "How would this sign be written in English?" (As opposed to second-language-English.)

I'd probably just leave out the "sticks".  So, "Cigarettes: 800 / Cigars: 200" and so on.

If you really wanted to replace "sticks" with a single word (for some reason), probably "pieces". If you wanted to extremely anally distinguish between cigarettes and packets of cigarettes, you'd say "Cigarettes: 800 individual cigarettes" and so on.

---

**Footnote!** thanks to oerkelens, we have the remarkable fact that apparently this is the more-normal term **in India**.

Again just TBC if a person from (let's say) Britain or the USA, who speaks and only speaks English, was passing that sign, in Greece, and looking at it: the person would simply find it to be **an incorrect word usage** (perhaps humorous). It's a "poor-machine-translation-moment".

Comment: Your assumption that your dialect of English represents the only non-silly way of speaking that language has the tendency to sound a bit arrogant... apart from it being blatantly wrong. First you claim that the word is "silly" and non-native, then you wonder if there is a hypernym for cigarettes, cigars and the like. You are not aware of such a hypernym, leaving open the possibility of the hypernym being "stick"...

Comment: Right, I did not know the best way to phrase "it sounds like a second-language speaker".  (I personally find that phrase extremely insulting.)  Can you help me with a better way to phrase that?  (ie, when a word is used that, well, sounds like it was chosen by someone who very much does not speak English natively)

Comment: I did a quick edit until someone ses the better way to express that!   {PS "stick" is not the English word for the superset (cigarettes, cigars).}

Comment: You could say that it is not a word that you, as a native speaker would use. Extending it to all native speakers would be an option, but in this case, native speakers of at least InE _do_ use it, so you would be stuck with saying it sounds like nothing that native speakers of AmE, BrE, AuE would say - as far as you know. With the risk of being challenged on that by someone whose grandpa called them sticks, of course :P.

Comment: Let me explain what I mean: a person from Britain (a native Briton, and solely a British-English speaker) passing that sign, in Greece, and looking at it: find it humorous, a humorously-incorrect word usage by a person who can't speak English and perhaps "used Google translate".  It's a "google-translate-humour-moment". (Obviously, depending on their temperament, they may not find it "humorous" but if asked, would say "someone who can't speak English used google to translate that".)  It's **Just That Simple**.  So it's a sign in Greece, that's the full answer.

Comment: (Your **additional, wholly remarkable, tremendously (to me) interesting input** that "sticks" appears to be the fairly common usage in **India** is entirely unrelated; since the question is about a sign in Greece and the site is about The English Language. As a default, every question on here is about "mainstream" English (so, largely BrE and AmE, if you will).  (By all means - by all means - **any question whatsoever on here**, there could be an astounding footnote such as "...but surprisingly, that is the normal term in India/Tasmania/HK...")

Comment: The same would go for an American seeing _fags for sale_ in Britain, of course. Or wondering why a kid is buying rubbers.

Comment: "As a default, every question on here is about "mainstream" English (so, largely BrE and AmE, if you will)" — I doubt you get to decide that the fastest growing dialect of English which is estimated to have more native speakers than BrE and AmE combined within decades is to be considered off-topic here, or not "mainstream" English.

Comment: **Yes**, how exactly correct.  Exactly as you say in some cases there is a distinct difference BrE/AmE.

Comment: "I doubt if you get to decide" ... the solution could not be more simple.  **Ask the OP** if he meant: "how would an InE speaker see this usage?"  Every question on this site is about a word, grammar, or other aspect of language. It is an utter certainty, as of today, that **in the absence of InE specifically being mentioned** then the OP means BrE or AmE (or indeed is not even differentiating between the two). By all means check with the OP.  it might be that I am completely wrong, and, the OP answers "Yes, of course I meant InE specifically." So, go ahead and ask.